# Calculate the exponent of the degree distribution if the distribution follows a power law

Tags: python, networkx

I try to use "powerlaw" library to fit this plot but it seems to have "0" values in the data. Is there an alternative way to find and calculate the exponent of this plot?
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degree_dist = [0.0, 0.0, 0.087, 0.105, 0.088, 0.081, 0.072, 0.058, 0.04, 0.037, 0.035, 0.035, 0.021, 0.018, 0.015, 0.024,
               0.015, 0.02, 0.018, 0.01, 0.01, 0.016, 0.005, 0.005, 0.008, 0.005, 0.008, 0.008, 0.009, 0.005, 0.002,
               0.003, 0.003, 0.005, 0.003, 0.004, 0.007, 0.006, 0.002, 0.006, 0.007, 0.003, 0.004, 0.001, 0.001, 0.004,
               0.003, 0.006, 0.002, 0.006, 0.002, 0.001, 0.003, 0.003, 0.001, 0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.004, 0.001, 0.003,
               0.003, 0.005, 0.0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.0, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001,
               0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0,
               0.0, 0.002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
               0.0, 0.001]
degrees = range(len(degree_dist))
plt.scatter(degrees, degree_dist)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Degrees')
plt.ylabel('Distribution')
plt.title('Degree distribution')
plt.show()
```

and here is the plot: [Degree distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKHzA.png)

Comment: You could 1. filter the zeros (like your graph is doing) / 2. add a small (1e-5) offset to all the points, then subtract it from the output to get the final equation / 3. Fit it to minimize absolute error instead of error wrt the log.

Comment: What do the `0.0` represent? Can you just filter those degrees out? Meaning, both from x and y arrays of course.

Comment: - I am learning about the degree distribution. The value is the fraction of nodes that have degree k, so i think the value `0.0` is very important and can not be filter.
- Can you show me your example code for the 2. and 3. solution please @arrmansa, i could really appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: If you think about what having bins with 0 counts means, something has gone wrong, because y ~ x^-a will never touch the x axis. Play around with your model and think about how it could be made to touch the x axis while still preserving some power law structure and then go back to what you have from there.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import math

def get_distribution():
    y = [1]
    while min(y) > -0.01:
        x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
        a = np.random.uniform(0.3, 0.6)
        b = np.random.uniform(0.5, 1.5)
        y = np.exp(-x * a + b) + np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, x.shape)
    return x, y, a, b

# Data

x, y, a, b = get_distribution()

# Plot

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Degrees')
plt.ylabel('Distribution')
plt.title('Degree distribution')
plt.show()

# Absolute error
def target_function_1(x, a, b):
    return math.e ** (-x * a + b)
((a_pred, b_pred), _) =  curve_fit(target_function_1, x, y)
print(a, a_pred, b, b_pred)

# Plot
 
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, [target_function_1(i, a_pred, b_pred) for i in x])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Degrees')
plt.ylabel('Distribution')
plt.title('Degree distribution')
plt.show()

ymin = min(y)
def target_function_2(x, a, b):
    return math.e ** (-x * a + b) - 2*ymin + 1e-5
((a_pred, b_pred), _) =  curve_fit(target_function_2, x, y)
print(a, a_pred, b, b_pred)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, [target_function_2(i, a_pred, b_pred) for i in x])
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Degrees')
plt.ylabel('Distribution')
plt.title('Degree distribution')
plt.show()
```

[image: initial scatter]
[image: absolute fit]
[image: subtract fit]

Comment: Thank you @arrmansa for the code. But i expect the curve fit to be linear ( a straight line) since we plot this distribution in a log scale. When i change the `targer_function_1` to `return C * x ** (-a)`, the result is a linear but quite disappointed. Do you have any suggestion for this, thank you

Comment: I don't think you can get linear results with log-log while trying to fit an exponential. If you think about it - you'll end up doing log(y) = m*log(x) + c which is y = e^(m*log(x) +c) . You would get linear fit only if you use a log-normal plot.